# On-click on draggable marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have google map in my application which loads several markers i handled the marker click by making my whole google map implements onMarker click listener its working fine i have also markers that are draggable implementations of it is also working fine but markers that are draggable if i click on it simple click the app crashes but if i do the usual way on the draggable marker which is long click to drag it it works fine how to manage to solve the single click on the draggable marker to crash my application or disable single click in it.Any solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your code for better explanation?

Comment: i mannaged to solve it now i just made my marker have a snippet in that way i could handle it on marker click that will tell the user to long press on it in order to drag it in a toast :)